# POST not working while using express + bootstrap modal

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I made a register form using the bootstrap modal and I can't seem to make the POST request work.

This is the form in my en.pug file

```
#register.modal.fade(tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="register form" aria-hidden="true")
        .modal-dialog(role="document")
            .modal-content
                .modal-header
                    h5#exampleModalLabel.modal-title Sign Up
                    button.close(type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close")
                        span(aria-hidden="true") ×
                .modal-body
                    form(action='/register' method='POST' )
                        .form-group
                            label.form-control-label(for="name") Name:
                            input#name.form-control(type="text", placeholder='first and last' name='name')
                        .form-group
                            label.form-control-label(for="email") Email:
                            input#email.form-control(type="email", placeholder='name@email.com', name='email')
                        .form-group
                            label.form-control-label(for="password") Password:
                            input#password.form-control(type="password" name='password')
                        .form-group
                            label.form-control-label(for="password") Confirm Password:
                            input#confirmed-password.form-control(type="password" name='confirmPassword')
                        hr.mb-4
                    // /registration form
                        .modal-footer
                             button.btn.btn-secondary(type="button" data-dismiss="modal") Close
                             button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Sign Up
```

This is my server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const app = express();

// serve static files from /public
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.use(cookieParser());

// view engine setup
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');

// include routes
const routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);


app.listen(3000);
```

And this is the ./routes/index.js

```
var express = require('express');
const app = express();
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const cookie = req.cookies.language;
    if (cookie) {
        res.render('en', { cookie });
    } else {
        res.render('ro');
    }
});

router.get('/en', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('language');
    return res.render('en');
});

// GET /
router.get('/ro', function(req, res) {
    res.clearCookie('language');
    return res.render('ro');
});

app.post("/register", function (req, res) {
    console.log('Hellooooooooooooooooo!')
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I fill out the form and press the Sign Up button I expect to show "Hellooooooooooooooooo!" in the console but nothing happens and I can't seem to figure out why. Am I missing something here?

EDIT: I figured out that I made a mistake in the pug indentation and the submit button was outside the form, reason for which completing the form and pressing the sign up button didn't do anything

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `bodyparser middleware`.

We had to install `body-parser` before express version 4 update, but express now supports `body-parser` by default.

Just add

```
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML, in the `input tags` of the form of the bootstrap modal window, I used the `name` attribut (instead of the id attribute) and it is working.

Answer (score -1):

```
//install body-parser npm and require it
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')

//write code below of app.use(cookieParser()) in server.js

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

router.post('/', function(req, res){
 console.log(req.body) //here you will get POST data
})
```